# SwiftUI NavigationStack doesn't expand to fit parent when parent changes size

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am using navigation stack to navigate around a sheet, that changes size to match the content. When the sheet content changes size, the navigation stack is not resizing itself to match the new size of the sheet using PreferenceKeys, which cuts off the content of the stack!

[image: Screen two cropped]

I have tried adjusting .frame() on the navigation stack but I get the following issues:

- .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) - this does nothing
- .frame(height: sheetHeight) - this seems the best solution, but doesn't always update
- .frame(height: 1000) - this stops the issue, but on the third navigationDestination, makes the keyboard unusable when editing a text field.

Is this a bug with NavigationStack, or can it be fixed? Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var sheetHeight: CGFloat = 100
  @State var sheetIsPresented = false

  var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
      Button(
        action: {
          sheetIsPresented.toggle()
          sheetHeight = 100
        },
        label: {
          Text("Show Sheet")
        }
      )
    }
    .sheet(
      isPresented: $sheetIsPresented
    ) {
      SheetNavStack(sheetHeight: $sheetHeight, sheetIsPresented: $sheetIsPresented)
        .presentationDetents([.height(sheetHeight), .large])
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) // Tried geometry.size.height, sheetHeight, 1000
        .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
    }
  }
}

struct SheetNavStack: View {
  @State var path = NavigationPath()
  @Binding var sheetHeight: CGFloat
  @Binding var sheetIsPresented: Bool

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
      NavViewOne(
        path: $path,
        sheetHeight: $sheetHeight,
        sheetIsPresented: $sheetIsPresented
      )
      .navigationDestination(
        for: NavViewDestinationTwo.self)
      { _ in
        NavViewTwo(
          path: $path,
          sheetHeight: $sheetHeight
        )
      }
      .navigationDestination(
        for: NavViewDestinationThree.self)
      { _ in
        NavViewThree(
          path: $path,
          sheetHeight: $sheetHeight,
          sheetIsPresented: $sheetIsPresented
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

struct NavViewOne: View {
  @Binding var path: NavigationPath
  @Binding var sheetHeight: CGFloat
  @Binding var sheetIsPresented: Bool
    @State var sheetHeightSaved: CGFloat = 0

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("View One")
      Text("View One")
      Text("View One")
      HStack {
        Button(
          action: {
            sheetIsPresented = false
          },
          label: {
            Text("Back")
          }
        )
        Spacer()
        Button(
          action: {
            path.append(NavViewDestinationTwo())
          },
          label: {
            Text("Forward")
          }
        )
      }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .padding()
    .overlay {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear.preference(key: InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
      }
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self) { newHeight in
      withAnimation {
        sheetHeight = newHeight
          sheetHeightSaved = newHeight
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation {
          sheetHeight = sheetHeightSaved
        }
    }
  }
}

struct NavViewTwo: View {
  @Binding var path: NavigationPath
  @Binding var sheetHeight: CGFloat
  @State var sheetHeightSaved: CGFloat = 0

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("View Two")
      Text("View Two")
      Text("View Two")
      Text("View Two")
      Text("View Two")
      Text("View Two")
      HStack {
        Button(
          action: {
            path.removeLast(1)
          },
          label: {
            Text("Back")
          }
        )
        Spacer()
        Button(
          action: {
            path.append(NavViewDestinationThree())
          },
          label: {
            Text("Forward")
          }
        )
      }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .padding()
    .overlay {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear.preference(key: InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
      }
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self) { newHeight in
      withAnimation {
        sheetHeight = newHeight
          sheetHeightSaved = newHeight
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation {
          sheetHeight = sheetHeightSaved
        }
    }
  }
}

struct NavViewThree: View {
  @Binding var path: NavigationPath
  @Binding var sheetHeight: CGFloat
  @Binding var sheetIsPresented: Bool
  @State var sheetHeightSaved: CGFloat = 0
  
  @State var textInput : String = ""
  @State var textEditorInput : String = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("View Three")
      Text("View Three")
      Text("View Three")
      Text("View Three")
      TextField("Hint", text: $textInput)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      TextEditor(text: $textEditorInput)
        .frame(height: 200)
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .background(
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        )
      HStack {
        Button(
          action: {
            path.removeLast(1)
          },
          label: {
            Text("Back")
          }
        )
        Spacer()
        Button(
          action: {
            sheetIsPresented = false
          },
          label: {
            Text("Done")
          }
        )
      }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .padding()
    .overlay {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear.preference(key: InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
      }
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self) { newHeight in
      withAnimation {
        sheetHeight = newHeight
          sheetHeightSaved = newHeight
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation {
          sheetHeight = sheetHeightSaved
        }
    }
  }
}

struct InnerHeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) { value = nextValue() }
}

struct NavViewDestinationOne: Hashable {}
struct NavViewDestinationTwo: Hashable {}
struct NavViewDestinationThree: Hashable {}
```

Comment: Try making the sheet height the id. It is likely that presentation detents doesn’t redraw. This is kind of brute force. SwiftUI usually works from parent to child not from child to parent.

Comment: @loremipsum Yeah I thought that because the state was owned by the parent, when the child updated it, it would pass up to the parent. Adding the sheetHeight as the id seems to work well when navigating forwards, but not when navigating backwards.